# Выбор из массива дат ближайшую к текущей

Tags: php

У нас есть массив такого вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-02-22 00:20:00
    [1] => 2016-02-25 08:45:00
    [2] => 2016-02-25 19:10:00
    [3] => 2016-02-25 20:00:00
    [4] => 2016-02-26 15:55:00
    [5] => 2016-02-28 17:10:00
)
```

Нужно из него выбрать ближайшую дату относительно текущего времени.
Например, если сейчас `25.02.2016-14:45`, то ближайшей будет `2016-02-25 08:45:00`

Comment: преобразуйте в таймштампы и дальше просто обычный поиск минимума

Comment: @splash58 а можно пожалуйста конкретней про поиск минимума, буду благодарен за пример

Comment: берите абсолютное значение разницы элемента массива и текущего времени

Comment: начните писать и приходите, если что-то конкретное будет не получаться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/gB1mWv)

```
<?php

$dates = [
    '2016-02-22 00:20:00',
    '2016-02-25 08:45:00',
    '2016-02-25 19:10:00',
    '2016-02-25 20:00:00',
    '2016-02-26 15:55:00',
    '2016-02-28 17:10:00'
];

$now = time();
$past_dates = [];

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    if ($now >= $timestamp) {
        $past_dates[] = $timestamp;
    }
}

$result = 'unknown';

if (count($past_dates) > 0) {
    $result = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', max($result));
}

echo $result;
```